# Open cv Error : Assertion failed (IIR filter on video frames)

Tags: c++, opencv

in below code i want to apply temp_rec filter on movies frame.

But i got the error assertion failed.

with video_line_extractor function extract a time series of pixels in a row
then in the main i apply my temporal filter to all of the row of the image.

I know it is a inefficient native code but i can not use of opencv internal
function instead of my temp_rec function.

```
 int width_frame, heigth_frame, num_frames;
 VideoCapture cap; 


void temp_rec(float* in, float* out, int w, float tau) {

    float yp;
    float tauo = 1 / tau;

    for (int i = 0; i<w;i++) {

        if (i == 0) {
            *out = tauo*(*in);
        }
        else {

            out -= 1;
            yp = *(out);
            out += 1;

            *(out) = tauo*(*(in)) + ((exp(-tauo))*yp);
        }
        out += 1;
        in += 1;//prepare for calculate next element

    }


}

Mat video_line_extractor(int whichrow) {//extract a row of frames

    // Create a VideoCapture object and open the input file
    // If the input is the web camera, pass 0 instead of the video file name
    cap = VideoCapture("a valid path");

    int frame_counter = 0;
    Mat M_temp = Mat::eye(width_frame, num_frames, CV_8UC3);

    // Check if camera opened successfully
    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
        cout << "Error opening video stream or file :(" << endl;
    }

    while (frame_counter<num_frames) {

        Mat frame;
        // Capture frame-by-frame
        cap >> frame;

        // If the frame is empty, break immediately
        if (frame.empty())
            break;

        cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_BGR2GRAY);



        for(int j=0;j<width_frame;j++) //we in above first extract a movie frame that as we know it is a image
            //in this 'for' we extract that row data with a pointer to one of the row in th M_temp  
        M_temp.at<uchar>(frame_counter , j) = frame.ptr<uchar>(whichrow)[j];

        frame_counter++;
    }

    // When everything done, release the video capture object
    cap.release();


    return M_temp;

}



int main() {

    cap=VideoCapture("a valid path");

    width_frame = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
    heigth_frame = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
    num_frames = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);

    Mat image= Mat::zeros(width_frame, num_frames, CV_8UC3);//initalize input
    Mat image_o = Mat::zeros(width_frame, num_frames, CV_8UC3);//initialize output

    for (int jj = 0;jj < heigth_frame;jj++) {
        image = video_line_extractor(jj);

        for (int j = 0;j < width_frame;j++)
            temp_rec((float *)image.ptr<uchar>(j), (float *)image_o.ptr<uchar>(j), num_frames, 10);

    }


    imshow("Image", image);

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

edit: assertion error
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGGu0.png

Comment: What's the assert? Can you copy the error here?

Comment: added image of error.

Comment: Your image is CV_8UC3 which is Vec3d but you are accessing its pointer as float*. If you need float data - convert your image to CV_32FC3 (or even CV_32FC1, because it seems that you are working with gray rather than bgr)

Comment: thanks @Dmitrii Z. , it is work. just change type of image_o from CV_8UC3 to  CV_32FC3.

Answer (score 0):

```
int width_frame, heigth_frame, num_frames;
 VideoCapture cap; 


void temp_rec(float* in, float* out, int w, float tau) {

    float yp;
    float tauo = 1 / tau;

    for (int i = 0; i<w;i++) {

        if (i == 0) {
            *out = tauo*(*in);
        }
        else {

            out -= 1;
            yp = *(out);
            out += 1;

            *(out) = tauo*(*(in)) + ((exp(-tauo))*yp);
        }
        out += 1;
        in += 1;//prepare for calculate next element

    }


}

Mat video_line_extractor(int whichrow) {//extract a row of frames

    // Create a VideoCapture object and open the input file
    // If the input is the web camera, pass 0 instead of the video file name
    cap = VideoCapture("a valid path");

    int frame_counter = 0;
    Mat M_temp = Mat::eye(width_frame, num_frames, CV_8UC3);

    // Check if camera opened successfully
    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
        cout << "Error opening video stream or file :(" << endl;
    }

    while (frame_counter<num_frames) {

        Mat frame;
        // Capture frame-by-frame
        cap >> frame;

        // If the frame is empty, break immediately
        if (frame.empty())
            break;

        cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_BGR2GRAY);



        for(int j=0;j<width_frame;j++) //we in above first extract a movie frame that as we know it is a image
            //in this 'for' we extract that row data with a pointer to one of the row in th M_temp  
        M_temp.at<uchar>(frame_counter , j) = frame.ptr<uchar>(whichrow)[j];

        frame_counter++;
    }

    // When everything done, release the video capture object
    cap.release();


    return M_temp;

}



int main() {

    cap=VideoCapture("a valid path");

    width_frame = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
    heigth_frame = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
    num_frames = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);

    Mat image= Mat::zeros(width_frame, num_frames, CV_8UC3);//initalize input
    Mat image_o = Mat::zeros(width_frame, num_frames, CV_32FC3);//initialize output

    for (int jj = 0;jj < heigth_frame;jj++) {
        image = video_line_extractor(jj);

        for (int j = 0;j < width_frame;j++)
            temp_rec((float *)image.ptr<uchar>(j), (float *)image_o.ptr<uchar>(j), num_frames, 10);

    }


    imshow("Image", image);

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```